# Is it possible to abstract out common parts of template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

For example, I have multiple components for paged collections. Template example:

```
<div *ngIf="!isFormVisible">
    <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-info': filtered, 'btn-default': !filtered}" (click)="showForm()">Filter</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="createNew()">Create new</button>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default" *ngIf="isFormVisible">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Filter<button type="button" class="close" (click)="hideForm()">&times;</button></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="id">Id</label>
                    <div class="controls col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control [(ngModel)]="filter.id"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="userName">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter.userName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onFormReset()">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="busy">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-pull-left"></i> Loading...</h1>
</div>

<label *ngIf="!currentQuery.result?.length && !busy">No results</label>
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="currentQuery.result?.length && !busy">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="sortBy('id')">Id</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="sortBy('userName')">Username</a>
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="#user of currentQuery.result">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="manageUser(user.id)">Manage</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<pagination [currentPage]="currentQuery.pageIndex" [totalPages]="currentQuery.totalPages" (onPageClick)="onPageClick($event)"></pagination>
```

For a specific component I am interested only in filter input fields, table header and row template. All the rest is repeated for all components. Is it possible to somehow apply DRY principle to templates and abstract out repeating part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `<ng-content>` for transclusion.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'reuse-cmp',
  ...
  template: `
<div>some fixed content</div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
<div>some fixed content in the middle</div>
  <ng-content select=".below"></ng-content>
<div>some fixed content below</div>
`
})
class ReusablePart {}
```

then use it like

```
<reuse-cmp>
  <other-dynamic-content class="below"></other-dynamic-content>
  <dynamic-content></dynamic-content>
</resue-cmp>
```

Transclusion places all top-level elements that have a class `below` at the place where this tag is `<ng-content select=".below"></ng-content>` and the rest that doesn't match a specific selector where `<ng-content></ng-content>` is placed.

Comment: For completeness: http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

Answer (score 1):

You could create components for these different parts and leverage `ng-content` if you need to include other parts as inputs.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test'
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
}
```

You can use this component this way in another one:

```
<test>
  <div>
    Part to include in the test component template (see ng-content)
  </div>
</test>
```

In your case, it could be something like that:

```
<pageLayout>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="id">Id</label>
        <div class="controls col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control [(ngModel)]="filter.id"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      (...)
</pageLayout>
```

The template of the PageLayoutComponent component could be the following:

```
<div *ngIf="!isFormVisible">
  <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-info': filtered, 'btn-default': !filtered}" (click)="showForm()">Filter</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="createNew()">Create new</button>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default" *ngIf="isFormVisible">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Filter<button type="button" class="close" (click)="hideForm()">&times;</button></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```